# Service or application to auto sweep specified BTC private keys?

Tags: private-key, private-key-import, sweep

Is there a service or an application that will auto sweep a bitcoin private key to your own wallet? I want to monitor a few private keys and sweep them once they receive funds in it.

Comment: So basically a payment forwarder? If specific addresses receive funds, then forward those funds to a different address. Block.io has one but I haven't tried it. https://block.io/docs/payment_forwarder

Comment: thanks anyone has screenshots of how to get this to work?